# *ng-for is not working in angular 2 todo app

Tags: angular

I am writing an angular 2 app. In the quick start tutorial, all things are working fine but in my todo app, its not working.

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component, Template, View, NgFor, bootstrap, CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({
    selector: 'todo-app',
})

@View({
  directives : [NgFor, CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})

@Template({
    url: 'components/todo-app/todo-app.html'
 })

class TodoAppComponent {
  todos : Array;
  constructor() {
    this.todos = [];

    TodoFactory.getAll().then((data) =>{
       this.todos = data; // I got JSON in todos object.
    });
  }
}
```

**todo-app-html**

```
<div *ng-for='#todo of todos'>
    {{ todo.text }}
</div>
```

In my template, `*ng-for` is not working. Even when I try `{{ todos }}`, it shows all of the data. I searched a lot and found that I should pass `NgFor` core directives to the template like `directives : [NgFor]` This is also not working. Any single help would be appreciated.

Comment: No need to add `NgFor`, `CORE_DIRECTIVES`, `FORM_DIRECTIVES` to providers, they are provided by default.

Comment: What's the error message you get?

Comment: I didn't get any error in console. It is crystal clear.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/ebr2zq?p=preview It has to be related how you get your data but that part is missing from your question.

Comment: `@Template`? That's like alpha 10 or lower. You should set `templateUrl` in your `@Component` or `@View`.

Comment: I should update angular 2 first. Thanks for your hint :)

Answer (score 2):

You should `*ngFor` instead of `*ng-for`:

```
<div *ngFor="#todo of todos">
  {{ todo.text }}
</div>
```

Otherwise, you don't need anyore to specify the `NgFor`, core and form directives...

**Edit**

Perhaps you load your data outside the context of Angular2. In this case you could try to leverage the `NgZone` class, as described below:

```
class TodoAppComponent {
  todos : Array;
  constructor(private ngZone:NgZone) {
    this.todos = [];

    TodoFactory.getAll().then((data) =>{
      this.ngZone.run(() => {
        this.todos = data; // I got JSON in todos object.
      });
    });
  }
}
```

See this plunkr for more details: https://plnkr.co/edit/KKj1br?p=preview

Comment: Yes, I've already been tried the same, but unfortunately didn't work. Neither I get any console error.

Comment: How do you load your data?

Comment: I am loading the data from a factory ie `TodoFactory`.

Comment: I mean do you use an external tool? Here is a plunkr that works for ngFor: https://plnkr.co/edit/KKj1br?p=preview.

Comment: Because, if the tool you use is instantiated outside angular2, zones won't detect changes. To prevent from this, you could leverage NgZone...

Comment: Okay let me try first.

Comment: Your plunker gives me an error ie `Error: Array.from is not a function`. Will you please elaborate it for me?

Comment: Is it better like this? I added `es6-shim.min.js`... In Chrome, it works

Answer (score 0):

***Which version of Agular2 do you use????***
***For latest version you may try this,***

```
import {Component, Template, View, bootstrap, FORM_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/angular2';
```

change them  to,

```
import {Component,View,bind} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap}  from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {FORM_DIRECTIVES,CORE_DIRECTIVES,FormBuilder, Validators } from 'angular2/common'; // CORE_DIRECTIVES contains all common required API
```

then,

```
<div *ngFor="#todo of todos">
  {{ todo.text }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The angular team removed every dashes (-) from template directives in the beta releases.

Therefore:

ng-for, ng-model, ng-class,...

are now:

ngFor, ngModel, ngClass,...

when using angular2.0.0-beta.0 and more

Answer (score 0):

In RC version of Angular 2 , angular team has removed **#** from templating syntax inside ***ngFor** and has changed ***ng-for** to ***ngFor**   , Use **let** instead of **#**

Previously you were using

```
<div *ng-for='#todo of todos'>
    {{ todo.text }}
</div>
```

You should use

```
<div *ngFor='let todo of todos'>
    {{ todo.text }}
</div>
```