# Angular 2 - Common directives like ngIf, ngFor not working

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I just started learning Angular 2 and I'm stuck on making common directives to work. I'm on Angular version `2.1.1` and I'm receiving the error `Can't bind to 'ngforOf' since it isn't a known property of 'li'.` Same goes to `*ngIf` and other directives.

Some of the most relevant tips I've read from similar questions here on making it work:

- 1. Make sure to [use the correct spelling and casing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35844511/ng-for-is-not-working-in-angular-2-todo-app) of the directives in the view, like so `ng-if` should be `*ngIf`, etc.
- 2. Import `BrowserModule` in the root module and `CommonModule` in other modules where you want to use common directives. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39746142/how-make-ngif-directive-globally-visible-in-all-project)

So far, here are parts of my code implementing those proposed fixes:

**approot.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { AuthRequestOptions } from '../services/auth.request.options';

import { AppComponent } from '../approot/approot.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './approot.routing.module';

import { DashboardModule } from '../dashboard/dashboard.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    DashboardModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    {provide: RequestOptions, useClass: AuthRequestOptions}
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

**dashboard.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }     from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { DashboardRoutingModule } from './dashboard.routing.module';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';
import { DashboardHomeComponent } from './dashboard-home.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    DashboardRoutingModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    DashboardComponent,
    DashboardHomeComponent
  ],
})

export class DashboardModule { }
```

**dashboard.component.ts** (where I want to use `*ngFor`)

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {ListService} from "../services/list.service";
import {ListModel} from "../models/list.model";

@Component({
  templateUrl: '/views/dashboard/views/dashboard.html',
  providers: [
    ListService
  ],
  styleUrls: ['../css/dashboard/styles/dashboard.css']
})

export class DashboardComponent {

  lists: Array<ListModel>;

  constructor (private listService: ListService) {
    this.lists = [];
  }

  ngOnInit () {
    console.log(this.lists);
    this.listService.getLists().subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.lists = data;
        console.log(this.lists);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

**EDIT**
dashboard.html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
    <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
      <li class="active">
        <a>My Lists</a>
      </li>

      <li *ngFor="let list of lists">
        <a href="#">{{list.name}}</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also tried importing `BrowserModule` instead of `CommonModule` in `dashboard.module.ts` but still got no luck.

I learned that previous angular2 beta versions has `directive` attribute in the `@Component()` and directives should be declared there so that they can be parsed. This is already deprecated in the current version of angular and I wonder if this has something to do with this error, angular not recognizing common directives.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: add dashboard html too please.

Comment: I guess it should be `*ngFor=` instead of `*ngfor=`. It's case-sensitive

Comment: Added dashboard.html @SefaÜmitOray
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
    <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
      <li class="active">
        <a>My Lists</a>
      </li>

      <li *ngFor="let list of lists">
        <a href="#">{{list.name}}</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>

Comment: I use `*ngFor=` @yurzui

Comment: Your error is `Can't bind to 'ngforOf'` If you use `*ngFor` then it will be `ngForOf`

Comment: @yurzui - I added dashboard.html in the question/post. You can see I'm using `*ngFor=`. But the error says `Can't bind to 'ngforOf'`, don't know why.

Comment: I wonder, this should work. Everything looks correct.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, My mistake. Sorry for bothering guys. I'm using `gulp-htmlmin` plugin which modified the contents of my templates. I just needed to add `{caseSensitive: true}` to `gulp-htmlmin` options to allow for custom element attributes. Thanks everyone for the effort.